# WordPress: how to maintain "www" in the URL?

Tags: hosting, wordpress, url

I'm very new to web hosting. I started an account at JustHost and installed a WordPress blog. I would like to access it through http://www.adlerr.com (my blog), however when I type in this URL in my browser, it transforms to http://adlerr.com and then presents the blog.

What should I do in order to maintain the "www"?

Thanks

**UPDATE**: since the problem was fixed, if you click on any of the links above you'll get to http://www.adlerr.com

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you want the 'www' to appear? Maybe I'm weird, but I prefer the "www"-less versions of my domains, and have my wp instances strip it, and have my apache config yank it, too :)

Comment: @warren: take a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/33165/what-to-choose-www-mysite-com-or-mysite-com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wordpress is re-writing the url. Change the site address to www.adlerr.com in the preferences menu.

Comment: That was it. It's under Settings-->General-->WordPress Address (and Blog Address, I changed both)